# What does binding to a LDAP server mean?

Tags: ldap

I have googled for well over an hour, and cannot find and information that simply explains the protocol/concept. Re-binding seems to occur several times during the process of [LDAP authentication and authorization](http://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/ldap-authentication-authorization-dissected-and-digested/).

Can anyone help me understand this concept or share better well explained resources on this...? Thanks!

Comment: in the context of your document, 'binding' is telling LDAP that you would like to make a request in a specific context (like a specific user or client machine).

Comment: Related: SO, 2014-08-27, [*Is LDAP binding account required for user authentication?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519666/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An LDAP client transmits a BIND request to a server in order to change the authorization state of the client connection. When a client first connects to an LDAP directory server, the server sets the authorization state of the connection to `unauthenticated`. When the server receives a BIND request, the server sets the authorization state of the connection to `unauthenticated` immediately. Should the BIND request be successful, the server sets the authorization state of the connection to the state associated with the distinguished-name in the BIND request. LDAPv3 allows a connection to change states any number of times, with the caveat that no requests be outstanding when the BIND request is received.

## see also

- [LDAP: Authentication Best Practices](http://web.archive.org/web/20130801091446/http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/authentication-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 2):

Google...first link...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Binding is the step where the LDAP server authenticates the client
>   and, if the client is successfully authenticated, allows the client
>   access to the LDAP server based on that client's privileges.

Rebinding is simply doing the process over to authenticate the client.